# Is it possible to assign a shortcut to "Step Into Specific" in Visual Studio 2012 C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently discovered the "Step into Specific" option while debugging C++ in Visual Studio (using VS2012) which is really helpful especially if there are many constructors, smart pointers, etc.

However, as I'm mostly debugging using the keyboard (F9, F10, F11, Shift-F11) I wonder whether it was possible to add this function to the keyboard repertoire somehow ?

Alternatively, as I mostly use the "step into specific" command on functions like

```
void doSomethingInterestingWith(sharedPtrToDb->getEltFromDb(EltId(atoi(key))))
```

I wonder whether it is possible to create a shortcut that just goes directly into the outer function (`doSomethingInterestingWith()`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a **Debug.StepIntoSpecific** command with the default shortcut `Shift+Alt+F11` which shows a context menu with functions that you can select using keyboard.

Comment: That's useful. Now I wish there was a command that by default just selected the 99% case of interest without the extra popup menu - the function being called rather than its dozen or so parameters. (sadly I couldn't find any under Tools \ Options)

Comment: I wish this command automatically stepped in when there's only 1 result... :/