# Visual Studio : Hotkey/way to step into f() in statement a()->f(b(),c(),d()) directly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

While debugging, I am currently at this (next) statement :-

```
system<System_Body>()->executeFracture(calculateFracture(data));
                       ^^1               ^^2
```

How to step into `executeFracture()` or `calculateFracture()` directly and easily (without changing the code)?

Hotkey? Extension? Plugin?

### My poor solutions

- With `F11`, I have to step into `system<System_Body>()` first.
- I can also jump to the source of `executeFracture()` and press `ctrl+F10` from there, but it is not convenient.

### **Edit**

**MotKohn** and **TheUndeadFish** advised using ***step into specific***, thank!
Another [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407219/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-shortcut-to-step-into-specific-in-visual-studio-201) (I just found later) tells that its hotkey is `Shift+Alt+F11`.
The hotkey make the choices popup, nice.

### Edit 2 (Bounty Reason)

The existing answer (**TheUndeadFish**'s) requires me to move mouse to a correct choice on the popup.
(or press up/down to select choice)

I wish for a more convenient approach, e.g. :-

- I click at the word `calculateFracture`, so the caret (blinking |) move to it.
- Then, I press some certain hotkey using keyboard,
  VS will step into `calculateFracture()` **immediately**.

Comment: `F11` into `system<System_Body()`, then `Shift+F11` to jump out, next `F11` will make into `calculateFracture`, press `Shift+F11` again, and the next `F11` should jump into `executeFracture`. Unfortunatelly, I'm not aware of a more convenient method than a sequence of `F11` and `Shift+F11`.

Comment: @lisyarus Understand.  Sometimes I did that.  Thank.  :(

Comment: I have an option when I right-click "Step into specific" which gives me a list of functions on the line. This is in c# though I did not check c++.

Comment: @MotKohn It works in C++.   :)

Comment: @javaLover, would you please mark it as the answer if this issue has been resolved? So it could help other community members who meet the same issue find and research the answer easily. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Jack Zhai-MSFT  I get your point, but it is not 100% resolved.  I have to 1.press the hotkey 2.move mouse to pick the correct function 3.click it.     Although it can solve most inconvenience, it is still not a "direct" way as I dream (use only one hotkey/click). .  This is one of unaccepted answer for my questions that is closest to be accepted.  Thank for your good intention.

Comment: @javaLover, no find other better workaround,  like this VS2017 RC document about the contents "Run to Click under Debugging and Diagnostics": https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes, do you want to get a workaround like this function "Run to Click"? While stopped at a break state under the debugger, the Run to Click icon subtly appears next to the line of code that your mouse is hovered over, so we could debug code much more easily, but not very sure that whether it also meets your requirement or it is a workaround for you and it is the VS2017 RC new feature:)

Comment: @Jack Zhai-MSFT    After I read the link, I think TheUndeadFish's solution is better.   1. "Run to Click" works similar as Ctrl + F10.  It can only go to a line, not a certain function within a line.   2. "Run to Click" is in VS2017 but not VS2015.  .... I don't find any better solution either, but there is no proof that it doesn't exist.  I realized that in some (rare) cases, half year later, a true solution may appear.

Comment: @javaLover, I also think that TheUndeadFish's solution is better, that's the reason why I suggest you mark it as the answer before, at least,  TheUndeadFish's answer could help us and other members who meet the similar issue. But whether it has the best answer, it would be the opening issue. If possible, you could also submit a feature request to the product team:http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio. I will pay attentions to other community members' suggestions/solution:)

Comment: @Jack Zhai-MSFT I personally don't like removing the green tick from an answer that I accepted. For example, if I accepted a useful answer (older one) in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39339959/3577745), I would want to remove tick from it and give tick to the perfect solution later. It is like retracting my word, canceling a rep prize. It makes me feel bad.  ><

Comment: @javaLover, I will keep this case opening for you.

Comment: @javaLover To stop at a specific function call (in a statement with a lot of nested function calls) I switched VS2013 to display disassembly. Then I could set my breakpoint at the specific call. (For my luck, the C++ code as well as symbols were mixed in.) Probably not the solution you are looking for...

Comment: @Scheff  interesting, I will dig more about it.  It might be a better answer.

Answer (score 10):

Not a hotkey, but the closest thing I know of can be found on the right-click menu when your debugger is stopped on a line of code line that. You should be able to find an entry to "Step Into Specific" with a sub-menu giving the choice of all the functions from that line.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7ad07721(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 5):

**Shift+Alt+F11** is the default global shortcut for "Step Into Specific", which will bring up a context menu of all the methods you can step into from the current instruction.

Of course, you can change the shortcut via Tools->Options->Customize...->Keyboard dialog.

Otherwise, there is no feature that allows you to step into the specific method under the editor caret. Sounds like a nice idea that you should put up on [uservoice](https://www.uservoice.com/case-studies/microsoft-visual-studio/) for Visual Studio.

Comment: "there is no feature that allows you to step into the specific method under the editor caret."  Please provide evidence.  Even it is the truth, there might be some extensions that can do that.  We can't be sure, right?  :)

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant. There may be a 3rd party extension, but Visual Studio does not ship with that feature.

Answer (score 3):

Encouraged by the positive feed-back, I show another possibility using the disassembly.

Once the debugging has been started, the disassembly can be opened by context menu in source file view. Although, the disassembly is hard to read (at least for the unexperienced) some facts are helpful:

1. C/C++ expressions are mixed in as well as symbols for addresses.
2. The assembler command for function calls is simply `call`.
3. The function arguments are evaluated in reverse order (beginning with last argument) regarding their notation in source code.

[image: Snapshot of debugging in VS2013]

Playing around with this I observed the following behavior:

1. Source code and disassembly may be displayed side by side.
2. Once disassembly has been opened while debugging, it will be closed at end of debugging but will re-open in the next debug session automatically.
3. **Ctrl+F10** works in assembly too (the important fact concerning the question). Thus, every individual function call in a statement may be addressed.
4. Clicking into source view (i.e. focus in source view) activates source level debugging, clicking into disassembly activates disassembly.
5. Clicking into disassembly changes "Auto" to display registers but "Local" displays local variables even when disassembly active.
6. Placing break-points into disassembly is not a good idea. They seem to refer the op-code address and thus probably become worthless as soon as source code is changed and (re-)compiled.
7. When debugging in disassembly reaches code compiled of another source code file, the source code view is not updated automatically. However, there is a command "Go To Source Code" at top of context menu of the disassembly.

Comment: When I step-into (F11) disassembly, the code on left panel doesn't change the file to which it should focus on.   Can I make the left panel show line of code that match the current step in disassembly? (match two modes in 4.)

Comment: @javaLover You are right. I added 7. to note about this.

Comment: For future readers and myself, hotkey of "Go To Source Code" are **1.** `shift+F10` + `G`  *or* **2.** `the-button-near-Ctrl-that-act-like-Right-Click` + `G`.   ....  Scheff, do you happen to know other hotkeys of "Go To Source Code"?

Comment: @javaLover It is possible to assign accelerator keys to every command in VS: Main Menu/TOOLS/Options.../Environment/Keyboard. I could give you even the command name but my VS is in German - sorry.

Comment: Thank ... I think I found it ... it is around "GoToSourceCode" search word.  Thank for the upvote too. :)