# When debugging in codeblocks (C++) , can I choose to skip all the internal library calls and functions that opens up?

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

I am trying to debug my C++ code in the Codeblocks editor.
I always step-into since I need to track variables in each step carefully.
When I step-into certain lines of my code, often the debugger goes into an internal library function (a function which I did not create, such as 'allocator.h', stl_vector.h', 'new_allocator.h' etc.) which then opens up another internal function in the next step etc. etc.
This means that I for example have to press 'step-into' around 45 times to return to my actual code. It makes it impossible to debug my code.

TLDR: I want the debugger to only step-into the actual lines of my program that I wrote myself, and it should skip the lines that are internal functions in the library (such as 'allocator.h', stl_vector.h', 'new_allocator.h' etc.).

I tried searching online for this specific problem, but could't find a solution.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Step-Out-Of when you get into a library function.  This will return you to the call site and you can continue with Step-Into.

Comment: Have you tried just stepping into for things you wrote? For example, if you have a function called my_function(), and you call it in your main.cpp, then step INTO it so you can step through the function. However, if you have a vector of ints called my_vector and you call my_vector.push_back(3), step OVER that line (unless you want to see what happens in the stl vector class).

Comment: What you want is probably to use "step-over" and "step-out-of" when applicable. You are in control of your debugger, there is no reason to always click "step-into"!

Comment: It is more profitable to write unit tests than to configure and script code blocks debugging capabilities. Unit test will debug automatically forever while stepping in debugger remains tedious regardless of level of comfort that you build into it.

Comment: All the well-meant hints about step-over are not helpful. For an expression, where system-lib calls are nested as arguments in calls of own functions, there seems to be no other chance than "Step-In" directly followed by "Step-Out" when you got at wrong place. (This is how I debug daily - I don't know any other way.) (For IDE-builders, some kind of black-listing e.g. of libaries would be very appreciated!) There once was a similar Q/A regarding VS2013: [Visual Studio : Hotkey/way to step into f() in statement a()->f(b(),c(),d()) directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42212348/7478597)

Comment: Oops. Following the link, I provided I found out meanwhile there seems to be an improvement I didn't notice - at least for VS2017: [Step Into Specific](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41605203/7478597). Though, that's still not the kind of black-listing you require and I don't know if CodeBlocks provides something similar. (I thought, I should mention this in contrast to my complaints in my previous comment - to be fair.)